# XCode Asset Catalog can't use TIFF files

Tags: xcode, macos, tiff, asset-catalog

I have a macOS project in XCode, but when I try to add a TIFF file to the asset catalog, it doesn't work.

[image]

```
NSImage(named: "inspector_column")
```

^ This returns nil. I have also tried just having the image as a file in the bundle (outside of the asset catalog), but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I seem to remember reading somewhere that it only supports jpeg/png as assets. Did you see documentation which indicates that TIFF is supported?

Comment: about tiff files with xcode instructions https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html